# Knockout.js: Toggling Visibility Of Dom Elements Using Radio Buttons

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to KO and learning step by step.

I would like to toggle the DOM visibility based on chosen radio button value. My code is not working as expected, kindly help....

**HTML**

```
<div>
    Wanna see what is next? 
    <p><label><input type="radio" name="MyChoice" value="True" data-bind="checked: MyChoiceValue" /> Yes</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="MyChoice" value="False" data-bind="checked: MyChoiceValue" /> No</label></p>
</div>

<div data-bind="visible: isVisible">
    <h1>Hello World !</h1>
</div>
```

and my **Javascript**

```
viewModel = function() {
     var self = this;   
     self.isVisible: ko.observable(''),
     self.MyChoiceValue: function() {
         if(self.MyChoiceValue() === 'True') {
                 self.isVisible(true);
         } else {
                 self.isVisible(false);
         }
     }   
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel);
```

**jsFiddle**:

http://jsfiddle.net/gbhasha/tCQtp/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/tCQtp/6/

```
<div>
    Wanna see what is next? 
    <p><label><input type="radio" name="MyChoice" value="true" data-bind="checked:MyChoice.ForEditing" /> Yes</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="MyChoice" value="false" data-bind="checked:MyChoice.ForEditing" /> No</label></p>
</div>

<div data-bind="visible: MyChoice">
    <h1>Hello World !</h1>
</div>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>

var ViewModel = function() {
   this.MyChoice = ko.observable(true);

   this.MyChoice.ForEditing = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return this.MyChoice().toString();  
        },
        write: function(newValue) {
             this.MyChoice(newValue === "true");
        },
        owner: this        
    });          
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Can you explain about what the return thing does inside the read: block. (your code works even after commenting out that line..)

Comment: If you want to print out the value of the computed you need the read value e.g.  <span data-bind="text: MyChoice.ForEditing"></span> if you don't have the read this won't display

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the radio buttons to an observable. And test the value of this observable in the view.

```
var ViewModel = function() {
     var self = this;     
     self.MyChoiceValue= ko.observable();     
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

The view :

```
<div>
    Wanna see what is next? 
    <p><label><input type="radio" name="MyChoice" value="True" data-bind="checked: MyChoiceValue" /> Yes</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="MyChoice" value="False" data-bind="checked: MyChoiceValue" /> No</label></p>
</div>

<div data-bind="visible: MyChoiceValue() == 'True'">
    <h1>Hello World !</h1>
</div>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a9PhX/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: If you can make MyChoiceValue evaluatable to Bool you can get rid of equality test on the visible binding